# Неправильное декодирование информации в python socket

Tags: python, сокет, decode

При приёме информации (len_password) от куда-то берётся 9q. Хотя я выводил информацию и не как не могло это получиться.

Файлы:

**server.py**:

```
import socket

ip_port = ('127.0.0.1', 25565)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(ip_port)
sock.listen(100)

clients = {}

def sendm(message: str, sock=sock):
    len_message = len(message)
    sock.send(len_message)
    sock.send(message)
    if sock.recv(1).decode('utf-8') == '1':
        return True
    else:
        return False


def getm(sock=sock):
    try:
        len_message = int(sock.recv(3).decode('utf-8'))
        message = sock.recv(len_message).decode('utf-8')
        sock.send('1'.encode('utf-8'))
        return message
    except:
        sock.send('0'.encode('utf-8'))
        return None


def auth(sock=sock, clients=clients):
    len_password = int(sock.recv(2).decode('utf-8'))
    password = sock.recv(len_password).decode('utf-8')

    len_name = int(sock.recv(2).decode('utf-8'))
    name = sock.recv(len_name).decode('utf-8')

    if name not in clients:
        clients[name] = {}
        clients[name]["password"] = password
        return True
    else:
        for client in clients:
            if clients[client] == password:
                return True

    return False


while True:
    try:
        client, addres = sock.accept()
    except socket.error:
        pass
    else:
        print(clients)

        if auth(client):
            print(f'Connect with {client}. Addres is {addres}...')
            client.send('1'.encode('utf-8'))

            msg = client.recv(1024)
```

**client.py**:

```
import socket

ip_port = ('127.0.0.1', 25565)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(ip_port)

alias = 'Sock1'


def auth(password, name=alias, sock=sock):
    len_password = str(len(password))
    print(len_password.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
    sock.send(len_password.encode('utf-8'))
    sock.send(password.encode('utf-8'))

    len_name = str(len(alias))
    sock.send(len_name.encode('utf-8'))
    sock.send(name.encode('utf-8'))
    if sock.recv(1).decode('utf-8') == '1':
        return True
    else:
        return False
    print(8)


def sendm(message: str, sock=sock):
    len_message = str(len(message))
    sock.send(len_message.encode('utf-8'))
    sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    if sock.recv(1).decode('utf-8') == '1':
        return True
    else:
        return False


def getm(sock=sock):
    try:
        len_message = int(sock.recv(3).decode('utf-8'))
        message = sock.recv(len_message).decode('utf-8')
        sock.send('1'.encode('utf-8'))
        return message
    except:
        sock.send('0'.encode('utf-8'))
        return None


cycle = True
while cycle:

    print('Auth')
    if auth(password='qwerty123'):
        print('Ok')

        sendm('Hello, world!')
        msg = getm()
        print(msg)
    else:
        print('Fail on autho')

sock.close()
```

Вот трэйс бэк:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\k\server.py", line 59, in <module>
    if auth(client):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\k\server.py", line 33, in auth
    len_password = int(sock.recv(2).decode('utf-8'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9q'
```

Comment: Если вы отправляете два сообщения подряд, то они при получении могут просто склеиться. То что вы делаете в sendm выглядит опасно. Не легче ли разделить их например нижним подчеркиванием. Так вы будете точно знать, что все что идет до первого подчеркивания - длинна сообщения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут две проблемы:

1. кодирование длины сообщения
2. сегментация сообщиний

### Кодирование длины

Проблема в протоколе, а именно в том, как вы передаете длину:

```
    len_message = str(len(message))
    sock.send(len_message.encode('utf-8'))
```

Тут количество байт для кодирования длины зависит от длины сообщения. И не ясно как отделить байты длины от самого сообщения. Кодировка получается неоднозначная, т.е. разные сообщения могут приводить к одинаковой последовательности байт пересылаемой по сети.

Лучше зафиксировать количество байт используемых для передачи длины. Например, если ограничить длину строки 2**32 т.е. ~4 гигабайта, то достаточно 4 байта для длины.

Нужно превратить int в массив байт. Это можно сделать используя модуль `struct`:

```
import struct

len_as_bytes = struct.pack('I>', len(msg))
sock.send(len_as_bytes)
```

На приемной стороне, нужно взять первых четыре байта принятого сообщения и превратить в `int`:

```
received = ...

(message_len,) = struct.unpack('>I', received[:4])
```

### Сегментация

Далее обратите внимание, что нет гарантии, что вы получите данные такими же порциями, как и посылали. `socket.recv` может вернуть меньше данных, чем вы попросили. Например, вы посылаете длину 4 байта, а потом сообщение, например 10 байт используя два вызова к `send`. На принимающей стороне, может так случится, что вызов `recv(4)` вернет сначала 2 байта, и нужно будет дочитывать недостающие байты пока не накопится все, что было послано.

Так что нужно `recv` вызывать в цикле, накапливая пришедшие данные, кодом типа:

```
def myrecv(sock, to_receive):
    received = []
    while len(received) < to_receive:
        chunk = sock.recv(min(to_receive - len(received), 2048))
        if chunk == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        received += chunk
    return received
```