# Как вытащить данные или скачать xml файл из байтов полученных с порта

Tags: python, xml

```
Received data (279): b'POST /file.xml HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 66\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:8079\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)\r\nAuthorization: Basic Og==\r\n\r\n'
```

Мне нужно вытащить данные или скачать xml файл из этой строки байтов. Прошу помочь! Я пробовал через `xml.etree.ElementTree` но не выходить сделать парсинг самого xml файла через  io.BytesIO. Выводит ошибку `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0`.

Пример кода

```
import socket
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import io

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8079))  

sock.listen(1)  

conn, addr = sock.accept()  

print('Connected by', addr)

conn.settimeout(10)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(524288)  # читает данные из сокета.
    print("Received data ({}): {}\n".format(len(data), data))

    if not data:
        print('No data')
        break
tree = ET.parse(io.BytesIO(data)) 
root = tree.getroot()
entries = tree.findall('elem')  # findall() возвращает список элементов ROOT:elem.
title_element = entries[0].find('Acknowleged')  # Метод find() принимает запрос ElementTree

text = title_element.text

print("Perser text: " + text)

conn.send("Thanks".encode())

conn.close()
```

Comment: Самое интересно, что код в первый раз заработал, а во второй раз отказывается

Comment: Вы удалили старый вопрос, а в нем были комментарии, которые объясняют причины ваших проблем. Еще раз повторю, нет гарантии, что чтение с помощью `recv` вернет все данные, которые послал клиент. И эти нормально, что иногда приходят все данные, а иногда - часть, клиент может слать их по частям и в момент вызова `recv` клиент банально еще не послал само содержимое, т.е. сам файл в теле. Вам на стороне сервера,нужно собирать их пока не получите полный http запрос, как написано в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1319427/218971

Comment: В строке байтов, которую вы получили нет xml файла, там только заголовки. Данные самого файла еще не пришли. Так что парсить http заголовки трактуя их как xml - не получится, ожидаемо будет ошибка такая, как вы видите - некоректный xml.

Comment: Ну мне нужен способ гарантированно получить список из xml из программы. Мне просто нужно чек напечатать. Я уже весь гугл обшарил для конвертации этого заголовка. В общем, мне нужно получить точный адрес этого xml, чтобы tree.parse работал. Просто не случайно же он в первый раз заработал. Мне просто нужно решение моей проблемы. я удалил, чтобы кратко и ясно расписать проблему, чтобы помогли. Я просто уже не могу.