# Сокет-сервер не дожидаясь клиента отправляет запрос рабочему файлу

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, сокет

Прошу помощи помощи в решении проблемы с сокет сервером.

У каждого клиента есть свой id, сервер при получении сообщения от клиента должен проверять эти id и в зависимости от них пересылать полученные данные в разные модули с разным функционалом, но при запуске сервера он самостоятельно вызывает `LoaderData`, не могу понять как с этим бороться.

Сервер получает список, в котором содержится id и данные.

Для клиентов из списка `clients` их id отправляется в модуль в качестве аргумента.

```
import socket
import pickle
import threading
from upload_daily_report import report_gen
from loading_cash_data import LoaderData

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 9090
TYPE = socket.AF_INET
PROTOCOL = socket.SOCK_STREAM

print_lock = threading.Lock()
clients = ('client_1', 'client_2', 'client_3', 'client_4', \
    'client_5', 'client_6', 'client_7', 'client_8', 'client_9')


def threaded(clientsock, addr):

    while True:
        pal = clientsock.recv(1024)
        if not pal:
            print_lock.release()
            break
        else:
            data = pal.decode('utf-8')
            if data[1] == 'uploader':
                ans = report_gen(data[0], data[1])
                print('Получено от %s:%s:' % addr, pal)
                ans = pickle.dumps(ans)
                clientsock.sendall(ans)
                print('Отправлено %s:%s:' % addr, ans)
            elif data[1] == 'controller':
                pass
            elif data[1] in clients:
                ans = LoaderData(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
                print('Получено от %s:%s:' % addr, pal)
                ans = pickle.dumps(ans)
                clientsock.sendall(ans)
                print('Отправлено %s:%s:' % addr, ans)
            else:
                print_lock.release()
                break

    clientsock.close()
    print('Задача потока выполнена!')

def main():

    srv = socket.socket(TYPE, PROTOCOL)
    srv.bind((HOST, PORT))

    srv.listen(15)
    print('Слушаю порт', PORT)

    while True:
        
        clientsock, addr = srv.accept()
        print('Подключен клиент', addr)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=threaded, args=(clientsock, addr))
        print_lock.acquire()
        thread.start()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Во-первых, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1319427/218971. Во-вторых, что по вашему содержит переменная `data` и что может содержать `data[1]`?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA за ссылку спасибо. `data` это список с аргументами от клиента, `data[1]` это индекс id клиента в списке.

Comment: Неправильно. `pal` - это массив байт, `pal.decode('utf-8')` - возвращает строку, которая закодированна в этом массиве байт, `data[1]` - возвращает второй символ из этой строки, т.е. если вы записали в сокет `hello world`, то в `data[1]` будет один символ `'e'` (и это если пакет не будет фрагментирован, как описано по ссылке)

Comment: Это я все к тому, что сначала нужно решить проблему фрагментирования пакетов. А потом нужно правильно проверять, что пришло. Сравнения одного символа с целой строкой, как у вас сейчас, работать не будет

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, благодарю за объяснение))) но проблема в том, что еще на стадии запуска сервера вызывается модуль, я даже клиент включить не успеваю.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Проблема была в том, что импорт модуля находился в глобальной области видимости, после переноса импорта в функцию сервер начал ждать сообщение от клиента.

```
import socket
import pickle
import threading
from upload_daily_report import report_gen
# from loading_cash_data import LoaderData # нужно убрать импорт отсюда

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 9090
TYPE = socket.AF_INET
PROTOCOL = socket.SOCK_STREAM

print_lock = threading.Lock()
clients = ('client_1', 'client_2', 'client_3', 'client_4', \
    'client_5', 'client_6', 'client_7', 'client_8', 'client_9')


def threaded(clientsock, addr):

    while True:
        pal = clientsock.recv(1024)
        if not pal:
            print_lock.release()
            break
        else:
            data = pal.decode('utf-8')
            if data[1] == 'uploader':
                ans = report_gen(data[0], data[1])
                print('Получено от %s:%s:' % addr, pal)
                ans = pickle.dumps(ans)
                clientsock.sendall(ans)
                print('Отправлено %s:%s:' % addr, ans)
            elif data[1] == 'controller':
                pass
            elif data[1] in clients:
                from loading_cash_data import LoaderData # вставить импорт модуля в локальную область видимости
                ans = LoaderData(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
                print('Получено от %s:%s:' % addr, pal)
                ans = pickle.dumps(ans)
                clientsock.sendall(ans)
                print('Отправлено %s:%s:' % addr, ans)
            else:
                print_lock.release()
                break

    clientsock.close()
    print('Задача потока выполнена!')

def main():

    srv = socket.socket(TYPE, PROTOCOL)
    srv.bind((HOST, PORT))

    srv.listen(15)
    print('Слушаю порт', PORT)

    while True:
        
        clientsock, addr = srv.accept()
        print('Подключен клиент', addr)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=threaded, args=(clientsock, addr))
        print_lock.acquire()
        thread.start()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```